# How to show all iframe content after onload if its change?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am making some stuff for a company and they ask me to make an iframe that, when resizing (only the height), resizes the body to see the full iframe.

The iframe contains a form, and after you complete it, the iframe change adding to himself a resumen of the form, an image...

I have alredy try to make onclick, onchange and onresize events, with DOM and jQuery, change the height of the iframe and the div that contains it, change the height of the iframe and the body/document, use a setInterval to add the height of the iframe to the body height... and I cannot use third-party libraries, decision of the company.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframeCenter" src="#####" width="100%" height="auto" onload="changeIframeSize()" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">  
</iframe>
```

JavaScript :

```
function changeIframeSize() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeCenter");
  iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Actually, the onload function works, when the documents loads the iframe height change, but when the iframe changes, the body height does not do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** So what you'll need to do is whenever content is changed inside iFrame you need to send a signal outside the iFrame and should have a listener outside on the page and change the height accordingly.

Whenever a component is rendered or anything gets updated i use iFrame `postMessage` and window's `eventListener`, i communicate between the iFrame and the main page using these so you're on the correct path now all you need to do is inside iFrame pass the value,

```
const payload = 'updateHeight'
targetWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, payload)
```

and in the main screen add an `eventListener`

```
window.eventListener('message', (event)=> {
  if(event.data === 'updateHeight') {
   // change the height here by calling `changeIframeSize()`
  }
})
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for postMessage

**Additional Info:** If in future, you want a callback or want to pass a function outside or inside the iFrame you can go for [post-robot](https://github.com/krakenjs/post-robot), It helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

make other div right above the iframe. And change height of that div and make that iframe 100% height. 
I think this will help you. Otherwise you can make a custom javascript and jquery for make that part easily.